# How to see count of unread emails from the Mail app in the Mac OS menu bar?

Tags: mail.app, menu-bar

What's the best way to see the count of unread emails from the Mail app in the Mac OS **menu bar**? (Bonus points if I can use it to open the Mail app as well.)

I don't really use the Dock, and I've gotten used to apps like Airmail and Fantastical that use the Mac OS menu bar to show information, like e.g. the count of unread emails.

The best I could find after a quick search was https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/22042/mail-unread-menu (from [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6867644) thread), which looks like it hasn't been updated in ~6 years and might not work without also installing the [MailPluginFix](https://code2k.net/products/mailpluginfix/) plugin. Is that really the best way to do this?

I'm using Mojave.

Answer (score 1):

So I can't live without the mail count in the menu bar. I was using mail unread menu for a while until it wasn't compatible anymore, I then used Dockstar which wasn't updated anymore either.

I finally found my gem, and finally could update to Mojave.
It is [MBI](https://github.com/bteapot/MBI), you have to compile it yourself with xcode, but it works as advertised!